# Handling of 'periods' in the add_seasonality() function

Tags: r, prophet

I am attempting to work with Prophet using monthly data (i.e. one date point per month) and I am a bit confused on the appropriate handling of the 'periods' argument as the [PDF documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/prophet/prophet.pdf) specifies it should represent the number of days.

However, many other forums seem to point to it being the number of data points.

If I want to add yearly seasonality how should I approach this argument?  Do I input 12 or 365.25?

If I want to add monthly seasonality what would I enter?

The function seems to give me a better fitted line when I use 365.25, but I am not sure if that is just a coincidence.